# how to read messages which appear after `C-x C-c`?

Tags: hooks, message, quitting, exit

When I exit emacs via `C-x C-c` (`save-buffers-kill-terminal`) it prints a message in minibuffer. I can't read the message because the frame gets destroyed too fast.

I'd like to read the message(s), how can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the `kill-emacs-hook` and the `kill-buffer-hook`, and the hooks can also be run without killing Emacs by evaluating `(run-hooks 'kill-emacs-hook 'kill-buffer-hook)`, or, you can run just one hook at time ...  The `write-file-functions` hook may also have something interesting attached to it that gets triggered when saving buffers while exiting Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist thanks again. I did run `(run-hooks 'kill-emacs-hook)` and then had a look at the *Messages* buffer. You might write a answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When killing Emacs, there are several hooks that may end up being called -- including, but not limited to, `kill-emacs-hook`, `kill-buffer-hook` (when a buffer is killed), `write-file-functions` hook (if a buffer is saved).  A user can inspect a hook by calling `M-x describe-variable` and the name of the hook.  A user can run a hook by evaluating `(run-hooks NAME-OF-HOOK)`, which function accepts multiple arguments such that several hooks can be called.  The original poster has indicated in a comment above that `(run-hooks 'kill-emacs-hook)` triggered the functions that were of particular interest.